# Breakpoint for Wordpress image gallery

Tags: wordpress, mobile, gallery, responsive, breakpoints

I'm working on a new webdesign and I'm stuck at getting my images responsive in certain parts of the theme, have been searching and try different code snippets in the style.css and inline but have not been able to get any images resized on my phone and tablet.

The page in question: 
http://zephyrusrecords.be/zephyrus/records/
It's the album covers that I would want to reduce in size on the mobile phone or tablet....
Hope this is clear and I provided right info, if not sorry and thanks in advance anyway, been stuck on this for some time so would be great if somebody could help me with this..

All the best,
Michiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the css of these 3 elements **.table1**, **ul.img-list li** and **img** :

```
.table1 {
        align-self: center;
        width: 850px; /*   Remove this line or change to width: auto;*/
        table-layout: fixed; 
}

ul.img-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px; /*  Remove this line or change to height: auto; */
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; /*  Remove this line or change to width: auto; */ 
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /*  Remove this line */
    width: 100%; /*  add this line */
}
```

I recommend you add a class for your images or you can use **".table1 img"** instead.

The css changes will adapt automatically the size of each image box when you reduce the page size.

**UPDATE :**

For the hover part, you need to change the css of the element span.text-content :

```
span.text-content {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;  /*  Change to block */
    height: 100%; /*  Change to 100% */
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /*  Change to 100% */
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

If you want to center the text, you need to change the css of the element span.text-content again :

```
span.text-content {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;  /*  Change to flex */
    height: 100%;
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    align-items: center; /*  add this line */
    justify-content: center; /*  add this line */
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your quick response, this seem to have fixed it and now it does resize on the phone/ tablet, I do have another problem however, the ;hover with info is now smaller and also the :hover text is also not centered anymore and on the homepage there is allot of padding added above the album covers, do you happen to know a workaround for this, anyway thanks alot for the tips!!

Comment: Great stuff man, working like charm now. Only thing is is that the :hover text is now not aligned vertically anymore within the box, not sure if it could be by my mistake.. (accidentally removed something..?)

Comment: Thank you so much!!